# Building a "queryable" javascript/JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I want to build an object that's query-able by multiple parameters.  The way I came up with stores data in spans with data attributes and "searching" with jQuery works, but I don't like it.

For a quick demonstration, I keep my "data" like this:

```
<span data-color="red blue" data-name="bill" data-value="47"></span>
<span data-color="blue green white" data-name="jane" data-value="13"></span>
<span data-color="red" data-name="mary jack" data-value="35"></span>
<span data-color="green" data-name="bill" data-value="43"></span>
<span data-color="white" data-name="steve" data-value="123"></span>
```

So if I wanted to match all values with color "red", I could just do:

```
$("span[data-color~='red']").each(...);
```

If I wanted to match all named "bill" and color "green", I would search like this

```
$("span[data-color~='green'][data-name~='bill']").each(...);
```

While this feels kind of clever, it also feels kind of hacky, tricking Javascript into queries with CSS selectors.  Is there a better way that I can store and access the data?  Requests could be numerous so I want it fast and not making an http request to query the data server-side.  And in my situation, there could be hundreds of entries to search (another reason why I don't like the CSS selector route).

Thanks!

Comment: JSON won't help as there's no such thing as a *JSON object* - JSON is a string - did you mean a javascript object?

Comment: @CertainPerformance - the spans were just a hack to store searchable data.  And Jaromanda - the data will be saved as a JSON file read by Javascript is what I meant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use an ordinary Javascript array of objects instead, and then use array methods to filter, iterate, and so on. No jQuery needed. For example:

```js
const arr = [
  { colors: ['red', 'blue'], name: 'bill', value: 47 },
  { colors: ['blue', 'green', 'white'], name: 'jane', value: 13 },
  { colors: ['red'], name: 'mary jack', value: 35 },
  { colors: ['green', 'blue'], name: 'bill', value: 88 },
];
const reds = arr.filter(({ colors }) => colors.includes('red'));
console.log(reds);
const greenBills = arr.filter(({ colors, name }) =>
  colors.includes('green') && name === 'bill'
);
console.log(greenBills);
```

Comment: I like it.  Thanks!